# Built in 4G modem of Thinkpad X1 carbon (5th gen) is not deteceted in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, lenovo, thinkpad, modem, 4g

I am having a Thinkpad X1 carbon (5th gen) laptop with in build 4G mobile broad band modem. Even though the socket for the SIM card is available on the laptop, `mmcli -L` does not detect it. Is there some tool or patch I need to get installed in order to detect the modem. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same problem on Linux Mint 19 (Ubuntu 18.04) based

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
lsusb
```

See if your modem is on the list, if not, there's a hardware or driver problem:

If it is listed, ex:

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0cf3:0036 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:58c2 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 12d1:14dc Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Exec this command: `sudo usb_modeswitch -v XXXX -p 1f01 -J`

Replace **XXXX** with your device ID, ex: 12d1

Comment: it is not listed int `lsusb` and in `lshw`, from results I think the device driver is not there in `Ubuntu 16.04`, How do I get it